# Netbeans xDebug only runs once on Mac

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I'm running Netbeans on my Mac. I installed my local server using XAMPP and have installed xDebug. When I go to debug/breakpoint in Netbeans, I can get it to run the first time on index. However, after the first run it won't attach to xDebug again unless I restart Netbeans.

How can I make sure that Netbeans always attaches to xDebug? Also, how do I get Netbeans to debug something besides the index file?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you'll find any solution. I heard (and can confirm this from my own experience) that it is really hard to have Netbeans + xDebug working fine locally under XAMPP. I don't know, if this relates to Mac, but it is for sure true on Windows. My friend has absolutely no problems running PHP + xDebug + Netbeans on his Linux, while I have never succeeded running xDebug locally on Windows + XAMPP and heard that others has similar problems. It seems that xDebug and XAMPP doesn't seems to be liking each other...

Comment: @trejder I have been able to get it to work for short periods of time but never consistently. One thing I have noticed is it will not work at all if you have a non www subdomain.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help here much, as I don't have much experience with xDebug and absolutely none with Mac. I just wanted to let you know that I had horrible problems getting it to work (and failed -- Netbeans was unable to catch any result from xDebug) on localhost on Win, while my friend with Linux get it working nearly out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

In your **php.ini** add following

> ```
> ; XDEBUG Extension
>
> zend_extension = "**ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_XDEBUG_EXTENSION**"
>
> [xdebug]
> xdebug.remote_enable = off
> xdebug.profiler_enable = off
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
> xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
> xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "**PATH_TO_TMP_DIRECTORY**"
> ```

In NetBeans IDE go to **Tools > Preferences > PHP > Debugging**

> Debugger Port: 9000
>
> Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
>
> CHECK : Stop at First Line

Open your project. Go to **Project Properties > Run Configuration**. Set

> Run As: Local Web Site (running on local web server)
>
> Project URL: **http://localhost/PROJECT_PATH/**
>
> Index File: index.php

Save your project file
Restart Apache
Restart NetBeans, open project, then

Debug > Debug Project

You should see **http://localhost/PROJECT_PATH/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug** in the browser and NetBeans should stop at the first line of index.php

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try this out at work tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try **deleting all files on your tmp dir** set on `xdebug.profiler_output_dir`

I had a similar situation where xdebug would work only "once" - on the first page load. After I emptied the tmp folder it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Might be problem with incompatible version of xdebug. For example downgrading xdebug from 2.2.4 to 2.2.3 solves the problem. http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1038